# speed up in DC's scanning

Tags: multithreading, performance, powershell, attributes

I'm building a script which will go to each DC's and take the value from `modifyTimeStampe` values and then on take the maximum value as the following code, at the moment the code is too slow because now it goes to each domain and put the value to the array, then get the max value from the array out. I would like to speed it up. I was thinking to use multiple threads, but still looking for a better idea to implement.

```
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$Searcher.PageSize = 100 
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree" 
$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=$objectCategory)(objectClass=$objectClass))"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")|Out-Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("modifyTimeStamp")|Out-Null

Function modiScan{

    forEach ($users In $userObjects) 
    { 

            $DN = $users.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")[0]
            $dnarr.add($DN)|Out-Null
    }
    #$dnarr
    foreach($dnn in $dnarr){
        $error = $false
        $lastmd = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        ForEach ($DC In $Domain.DomainControllers){                    
            $Server = $DC.Name
            $Base = "LDAP://$Server/"+$dnn
            $Searcher.SearchRoot = $Base                    
            try{
                $Results2 = $Searcher.FindAll()
                ForEach ($Result2 In $Results2) 
                {   
                    $DN2 = $Result2.Properties.Item("distinguishedName")[0]
                    if($DN2 -eq $dnn){
                        $modi = $Result2.Properties.Item("modifyTimeStamp")[0]
                        if($modi){
                            $lastmd.Add($modi)|Out-Null                            
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch{
                $error = $true
            }                    
        }
        if($error -eq $true){
            $lastModi = "None-set"
            $global:noneModi++
        }
        else{
          $lastModi = ($lastmd |measure -max).maximum      
          if($lastModi -ne $null){   
                $lastModi = $lastModi.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                if($lastModi.split("/")[0] -eq 2015){
                     $global:modi2015++
                }       
                elseif($lastModi.split("/")[0] -eq 2016){
                     $global:modi2016++
                }
                elseif($lastModi.split("/")[0] -eq 2017){
                     $global:modi2017++
                }
                 else{
                     $global:otherModi++
                }
            }
            else{
                $lastModi = "N/A"
                $global:noneModi++
            }
        }
        #$lastModi
      $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "modi" -Value $lastModi      
      $obj | Export-Csv -Path "$outFileModi" -NoTypeInformation -append -Delimiter $Delimiter

   }
}
modiScan
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you are not using the cmdlets?

Comment: Directory Searcher is much, much faster than the AD Cmdlets. Also, there are several foreach loops in that script. That will slow things down for sure.

Comment: @Fairy, some particular reason I couldn't use cmdlets :/

Comment: @Jason I think it gets slow when it has to store the value to an array. Yeah Foreach loops are also the point

Comment: ArrayLists are better than arrays so that is a point in your favour. There are other minor things like you should be using `switch` instead of all those ifs. How many DC's do you have? Its possible your date checks could be improved. measure object is considered slow. A simple sort should be faster. I wouldnt expect huge gains there though. This code is incomplete because `$userObjects` is not defined from what I can see

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: @Matt thanks. I have 4-5 DC's. The `$userObjects` is just `$userObjects = $ADSearch.FindAll()` of the Domain Name.